# gzdecode and PHP?

Tags: php, gzip

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Decompressing a .gz file via PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4548824/decompressing-a-gz-file-via-php)

I cannot use gzdecode with php as it is not installed and I cannot install it,

I have been using this so far...

```
// GZIP DECODE
function gzDecode($d) {
$f = ord(substr($d, 3, 1));
$h = 10;
$e = 0;
if($f&4) {
    $e = unpack('v', substr($d, 10, 2));
    $e = $e[1];
    $h += 2 + $e;
}
if($f&8) {
    // ERROR HERE
    $h = @strpos($d, chr(0), $h) + 1;
}
if($f&16) {
    $h = strpos($d, chr(0), $h) + 1;
}
if($f&2) {
    $h += 2;
}
// ERROR HERE
$u = @gzinflate(substr($d, $h));
if($u == false) {
    $u = $d;
}
return $u;
}
```

It works but is there a better solution for PHP 5.3? If not is there any way I can get rid of the errors that are present?

Comment: Also no need to repost. You got the answer with a link to alternative implementations already last time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you had a look at some of the materials shown in the comments of http://php.net/gzdecode? The comments include [a simple way using `gzinflate()`](http://php.net/gzdecode#106397) and [a pure PHP implementation](http://php.net/gzdecode#82930) of the `gzdecode()` function you can lift entirely.

As a general rule of thumb, don't reinvent the wheel where you don't have to!